# Javascript - comparing two dates ( minus X days) to see whether it's true or false

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, comparison

I am trying to execute a code if a date (from a cookie) is older than about 2 days. More or less, it doesnt have to be precise.

The cookie value is : 2022-06-27T23:28:02.816Z

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

Using :

```
getCookie(name) and : .slice(0, 10);
```

Returns : 2022-06-27
Therefore I now have a YYYY-MM-DD value

```
var stuff_cookiename = getCookie("cookiename").slice(0, 10);
```

Converting to a date format :

```
var t_date_refuscmp_todate = Date.parse(stuff_cookiename);
```

I now have something like this : 1656288000000

Now I want to compare it NOW's date - 2 days
So I do :

```
var t_date_verif = new Date();
var t_date_verif_format = tc_date_verif.setDate(tc_date_verif.getDate() - 2);
```

Which brings me something like : 1656199936800

=====================

But if i compare my cookiedate vs todaysdate -2 days, it doesnt always seem to be working correctly.

```
t_date_refuscmp_todate < t_date_verif_format !!!
```

Any idea of what I am not doing right?
Maybe there is something a lot easier to do :)

Thanks !

Comment: Typo: `tc_date_verif` should be `t_date_verif`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: What result are you expecting, what are you getting instead? After I fix the typo I get `false`, which is expected.

Comment: Was indeed a typo when I worked my stackoverflow question but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^ A more specific(to your question)and simpler answer in my opinion

```
var diff = Date.now() - new Date("2022-06-25T23:28:02.816Z");

if(diff <= 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2){
    console.log("less than 2 days old");
}else{
    console.log("more than 2 days old");
}
```

Comment: A lot simpler and seems to be working perfecftly, awesome, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

Parse the cookie and the current datetime, convert it into epoch ms, sompute the difference in days.

**Code**

```js
let s_dtCookie    = "2022-06-27T23:28:02.816Z"
  , n_epochCookie = (new Date(s_dtCookie)).getTime()
  , n_epochNow    = (new Date()).getTime()
  , n_deltaDays   = (n_epochNow - n_epochCookie) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)
  ;

console.log(`Cookie time '${s_dtCookie}' is ${n_deltaDays} days in the past.`);
```

**Reference**

MDN JS docs, [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) section.

Comment: Another way to do it, thank you @collapsar !